# What privileges are needed to delete a read-only btrfs subvolume?

Tags: permissions, btrfs, snapshot

I want to delegate non-root user to delete read-only subvolumes (snapshots).

What exactly capabilities/rights I need to grant, so that he can remove his own read-only snapshots?

I've already mounted the btrfs with `-o user_subvol_rm_allowed` so users can remove read/write snapshots.

I need it to augment otherwise brillant [SnapBtr.py](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SnapBtr), so non-root users can operate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A user can not delete readonly snapshots directly, but he can make them writeable first and then delete them. For this you need to use the `btrfs property` command:

```
btrfs property set -ts /path/to/snapshot ro false
```

If the user is the owner of the snapshot, this should make it writeable and therefore deletable.

Comment: That is cool. Thank you! Too bad, that the btrfs-tools v3.12 present on Ubuntu 14.04 does not include this command - but that is a different story.

Comment: I also stumbled across this. TBH I think that's a plain btrfs bug.

Comment: Hint: If you run `btrfs property set -ts /path/to/subvolume ro false` and `rm -rf` still complains about `Read-only file system`, then make sure all nested subvolumes are also not read-only.